# How to extract users mentioned in a post? (VUE-NODE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

**What i have**

1. Create a title (input), body (input) and a mention user (input), 3 separated inputs

**What i want**

I want to create a mentioned functionality to a post like facebook,twitter where in the body you can add user to mention using @ (**users are aplhanumeric only**)

**What have i done?**

1. search users when press @ key and added to post body (the process to show users bla bla)

   input v-on:keyup.50="searchUsers()" type="text"

**What i need?**

I have no clue which is the best way how to extract that @username1 @username2 added to the post body to later insert it in the mentioned database, maybe:

1. Regex?
2. another one??

**Tech used** > Vue and Node

**Any articles or information to this matter will be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a Regex is a good solution.

I write a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cincarnato/pen/LYGQGmR) with an example

**PREVIEW:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" 
           v-model="title" 
           placeholder="title" 
    />
    <br><br>
    <textarea rows="20" 
              cols="30"
              v-model="body"
    ></textarea>
    
    <div>
      <h3>Mention users </h3>
      {{mentionUsers}}
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: null,
      body: "Hello, bla bla bla @jrambo bla bla bla @jwick bla bla bla @cincarnato",
      mentionUsers: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    identifyMentionUsers() {
      this.mentionUsers = this.body.match(/@\w+/g);
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.identifyMentionUsers()
  },
  watch: {
    body(val){
      this.identifyMentionUsers()
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly, by the way, when we make a get request to see the posts, i can use regex to create a a html tag to create that @username clickable?

Comment: Yes, you can use regex + replace for that purpose, adding tag a to mention users: <a> @user </a>

Comment: any example? i really never tried regex before. If you want the points, i can make another question, its ok for you ?

Comment: Yes, I can write an example for you. I will write another codepen. If you can, make another question, I will share the example with you when its done.

Comment: Here the codepen with the replace example: https://codepen.io/cincarnato/pen/wvMyzEx

Comment: excellent, give me 5 minutes to create the question, ill paste the link here

Comment: there you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733767/how-to-change-users-mentioned-to-a-html-a-tag-in-a-post-vue-node

Comment: Hi , now i want to remove the @ from that array items, how can i do it?

Comment: i did like this, i dont is this is the best possible way (performance).
                var mm= [];
                for(let m of req.body.body.match(/@\w+/g)){
                    mm.push(m.replace(/^@+/, ""))
                }