# How to change users mentioned to a html a tag in a post? (VUE-NODE)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a body property that contains text that involves @username1 @username2. I want to change where are nicknames @user1 @user2 etc to router-links, its possible to do it with regex?

**The final code need to be like this (without the @ in link profile)**

```
<router-link :to='/profile/username1'></router-link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share the solution in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/cincarnato/pen/wvMyzEx)

**CODE:**

```
<template>
<div>
  
  <h3>Original</h3>
  <div id="original" class="box">
    {{body}}
  </div>
  
  <h3>Replaced</h3>
  <div id="replaced" 
        class="box"
        v-html="bodyReplaced"
  ></div>
  
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      body: 'Hi @jrambo and @jwick I am @cincarnato',
      
    };
  },
  computed: {
    bodyReplaced(){
      /* Using string.replace
         1 parameter: regex to match
         2 parameter: a function that return the new text (the funcion receive the string matched by regular expression)
      */
      return this.body.replace(
        /@\w+/g, 
        (user) => '<a href="#" >'+user+'</a>'
      )
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
  .box{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hello please check the edit question, hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Use named routes and params for route

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { username: yourUserNameProp }}"></router-link>
```

Named routes:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { name:'user', path: '/profile/:username', component: User }
  ]
})
```

Comment: hi, the problem is if i change de a tag for a router-link tag nothing happens, im using the code in the answer on top @deffox

Comment: I need to find in the body property, where @user and change it to router-link to be clickeable